# How to open file daisy protected?

Tags: ebook-readers

I downloaded a file daisy from the Internet Archive but it can't open by the program ( Setup-amis-U.S.English ) said protected ? So which program can open it just to read .. I tried the Adobe Digital Editions 4.5 it can't open it

Comment: This part (  package.ppf )  is only can be opened but unreadable to change to pdf

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/585642/how-to-read-daisy-format-book

Comment: Or more general Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAISY_Digital_Talking_Book